# How can I add background image in RAP Application?

Tags: background, rcp

In RCP application I can easily add a background image using SWT and window builder. But how can I add background image for RAP applications ? Can anyone help me with a simple example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Button-CheckIcon:selected {
    background-image: url( images/check-selected_red.png );
 }
```

You can see the details in [this link](http://www.codeaffine.com/2012/08/14/rap-adapt-your-style/)

Comment: This tutorial is for button icon selection and not properly understandable. If u have any other solution please reply